# Changing network of GCP dataflow jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, google-cloud-dataflow

There is a requirement to change the network of more that 1000 `dataflow` jobs . Right now they are running in default network and we need to change the jobs to use `custom/shared VPC` . I thought of using below `gcloud dataflow` which supports `--network parameter` to change network but it may not work for all the jobs .

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run wc --gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/Word_Count --region us-central1 --subnetwork regions/us-east1/subnetworks/newkube --disable-public-ips
```

My main concern is if I change the network using the above command then it will invoke the `dataflow` job too which means resources used by the job will be launched again . This is inflating the cost for me just to change the network .

Any suggestions to change the network for existing jobs without running the job so that during the next run it runs on the new network .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run the job to change the network. Whatever Orchestration tool that you are currently using to trigger these dataflow jobs you would need to go and make changes to add the `network` and `subnetwork` (if required).

When the orchestration tool executes the dataflow job it will use the `network` parameter to spin up the workers within that VPC. Each time the job runs it checks for these configurations and accordingly spins up the worker machine.

Comment: Any way to identify the orchestration tool being used for the jobs using `gcloud dataflow describe` command. Which parameter will give that info ? I am aware some jobs are launched using `cloud composer ` but I need to check for these thousand jobs. Since I am not the owner of these jobs , some option to identify it will be helpful